# Parsing a CSV file using array of hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, csv, file-io, hash

I have CSV data in this form:

```
Sl.No, Label, Type1, Type2...
1, "label1", Y, N, N...
2, "label2", N, Y, Y...
...
```

Where "Y" and "N" denote whether the corresponding label is to be printed to a file or not.

```
while ( <$fh> ) {    #Reading the CSV file

    $filter = $_;
    chomp $filter;
    $filter =~ tr/\r//d;

    if ( $. == 1 ) {
        @fieldNames = split ",", $filter;
    }
    else {
        @fields = split ",", $filter;
        $numCustomers = scalar(@fields) - 2;
        push @labels, $fields[2];

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $numCustomers; $i++ ) {

            for ( $j = 0; $j < scalar(@labels); $j++ ) {
                $customer[$i][$j] = $fields[ 2 + $i ];
            }

            $custFile = "customer" . $i . "_external.h";

            open( $fh1, ">", $custFile ) or die "Unable to create external header file for customer $i";
        }
    }
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < scalar(@labels); $i++ ) {

    for ( $j = 0; $j < $numCustomers; $j++ ) {

        $Hash{ $fieldNames[ 2 + $i ] }->{ $labels[$i] } = $customer[$j][$i];
        push @aoh, %Hash;    #Array of hashes
    }
}

my @headerLines = read_file($intFile);  # read the internal file, and copy only
                                        # those lines that are not marked with
                                        # "N" in the CSV file to the external file.

# iterate over elements of each hash and print the labels only if value is 'Y'

foreach my $headerLine (@headerLines) {

    chomp $headerLine;

    for $i ( 0 .. $#aoh ) {

        for my $cust1 ( sort keys %{ $aoh[$i] } ) {    #HERE

            for my $reqLabel1 ( keys %{ $aoh[$i]{$cust1} } ) {

                print "$cust1, $reqLabel1 : $aoh[$i]{$cust1}{$reqLabel1}\n";

                if ( $aoh[$i]{$cust1}{$reqLabel1} eq "Y" ) {

                    for ( $j = 0; $j < $numCustomers; $j++ ) {
                        $req[$j][$i] = $reqLabel1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for ( $j = 0; $j < $numCustomers; $j++ ) {
                        $nreq[$j][$i] = $reqLabel1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        if ( grep { $headerLine =~ /$_/ } @nreq ) {
            next;    #Don't print this line in the external file
        }
        else {
            print $fh1 $headerLine . "\n";    #print this line in the external file
        }
    }
}
```

This complains "Cannot use string Type1 as a hash REF", referring to the line marked as #HERE.

I've tried dumping data structures everywhere, but I'm not sure where this cropped up from.

Any insights would be appreciated.

I have received feedback that using `Text::CSV` would be a better solution. How would it reduce the need to use nested data structures?

Comment: What's the expected output for the given sample input?

Comment: The lines in `$intFile` are written into the external file (`print $fh1 $headerLine."\n";`); except if the line is marked with "N" in the CSV.

Comment: And there's a separate external file for every "type" in the CSV.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Because I'll point out - `Text::CSV` supports named columns, so you don't actually have to muck about with hashes and slices.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: I did. And I do. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your problem gets a lot easier with `Text::CSV`. I would suggest looking at a rewrite, or reasking your question framing it as such.

But your problem is actually this:

```
push @aoh, %Hash;                #Array of hashes
```

That doesn't create an array of hashes at all. That extracts all the elements from  `%Hash` (in no particular order, aside from keys and values being paired) and inserts them into `@aoh`.

You *probably* want:

```
push @aoh, \%Hash;
```

Or perhaps:

```
push @aoh, { %Hash };
```

I'm not entirely clear, because you're reusing `%Hash`, so you may get duplication. This is best dealt with by `use strict;` `use warnings;` and lexically scoping your hashes correctly.

Comment: I accept that using `Text::CSV` would be a cleaner solution, but I'd like to get my way out of this mess with my eyes open. 

I understand the mistake I made there, and I have used `strict` and `warnings`. Could you please elaborate on lexically scoping my hashes correctly? I'd be grateful.

Comment: Well, because you don't _declare_ `%Hash` with `my`, `perl` treats it as a global variable. And so each time you do : `$Hash{$fieldNames[2 + $i]}->{$labels[$i]} = $customer[$j][$i];   ` you add a new element to the existing hash. But don't delete the old one, so if you try and insert it into your array at this point, you'll have dupes. If you scope your hash to the loop though (with `my`) then it creates a _new_ data structure each iteration.

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` is invaluable for this sort of things.

Comment: Absolutely. I have more commented `print Dumper(....)` lines than anything else. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd just keep an array of open file handles (if there aren't too many Types) and print to them while reading the file line by line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

chomp( my $header = <> );
my @names = split /, /, $header;

my @handles;
for my $type (@names[ 2 .. $#names ]) {
    open my $fh, '>', $type or die "$type: $!";
    push @handles, $fh;
}

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /, /;
    for my $index (0 .. $#handles) {
        print { $handles[$index] } $fields[1], "\n" if 'Y' eq $fields[ $index + 2 ];
    }
}
```

I used the following input to test it:

```
Sl.No, Label, Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4
1, "label1", Y, N, Y, N
2, "label2", N, Y, Y, N
```

If your input contains the `\r` line ends, set [binmode](http://p3rl.org/binmode) to `:crlf`.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something - could you please explain `chomp( my $header = <> );`?

Comment: `<>` in scalar context reads a line from the input, `chomp` removes the final newline.

Comment: I also need to check if the lines (even if marked "Y") exists in another ("internal") file before printing it to the output file.

Comment: @AnupamaG: hash the internal file first.

Comment: How can I read the files I've written to right now? 
Here's what I did, based on what you kindly told me:


    `$numCustomers = scalar(@names) - 2;

    for(my $i = 0; $i < $numCustomers; $i++)

    {
 my $custFile = "customer".$i."_external.h";

        open my $fh, '>', $custFile or die "$custFile: $!";

        push @handles, $fh;

        push @files, $custFile;

    }`

And later:

    `for(my $i = 0; $i < $numCustomers; $i++) 

    {

 my @Lines = read_file($files[$i]);

 #do something

    }`

This read_file doesn't work (I'm using `File::Slurp`). Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @AnupamaG: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Try printing the contents of the array, verifying the files are there and inspecting their contents.

Comment: The files are created. What I mean by "doesn't work" is that `@Lines` is empty. I apologize for my lack of English expertise.