# Perl: Inserting values into specific columns of CSV file

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, file-io

I have CSV data of the form:

```
S.No,Label,Customer1,Customer2,Customer3...
1,label1,Y,N,Y
2,label2,N,Y,N
...
```

I need to reproduce the "label" to the *left* of "customer" columns marked with **Y** - and have nothing (`""`) to the left of columns marked with **N**.

Expected output:

```
S.No,Label,Customer1,Customer1,Customer2,Customer2,Customer3,Customer3...
1,label1,label1,Y,"",N,label1,Y
2,label2,"",N,label2,Y,"",N
```

When opened using Excel, it would look like this:

```
S.No   Label      Customer1   Customer1   Customer2   Customer2   Customer3   Customer3...
   1   label1      label1        Y                       N        label1          Y
   2   label2                    N         label2        Y                        N
```

The two leftmost columns, referring to S.No and the original "Label" column, are **constant**.

What is the simplest way to do this? I tried the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $nonIncludesFile = "nonIncludes.csv";
open(my $xfh, "+>", $nonIncludesFile) or warn "Unable to open $nonIncludesFile, $!";
chomp( my $header = <$xfh> );
my @names = split ",", $header;
my @names1;
my @fields;
my @fields1;
for(my $j=0; $j< scalar(@names); $j++)
{
    $names1[$j] = $names[$j];
}
while(<$xfh>)
{
    my $nonIncLine = $_;
    $nonIncLine = chomp($nonIncLine);
    @fields = split ",", $nonIncLine;
    next if $. == 1;                      #skip the first line

    for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@fields) -2; $i++)   #Number of "customers" = scalar(@fields) -2
    {
        $fields1[0] = $fields[0];
        $fields1[1] = $fields[1];
        if('Y' eq $fields[ $i + 2 ])
        {
            $fields1[$i+2] = 'Y';
            substr(@fields1, $i + 1, 0, $fields[1]);   #insert the label to the left - HERE
        }
        else
        {
            $fields1[$i+2] = 'N';
            substr(@fields1, $i + 1, 0, "");
        }
    }
}

print $xfh @names1;
print $xfh @fields1;

close($xfh);
```

This however complains of "substr outside of string" at the line marked by "HERE".

What am I doing wrong? And is there any simpler (and better) way to do this?

Comment: Your example does not have a case where there is no customer with a **Y**. Since there is only one label column, which customer column does it refrence? Please [edit] your question and specify the requirements and add expected output. Also ammend your code to `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: How is the question different to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34809165/1030675 ?

Comment: I was referring there to a specific problem involving errors in syntax and semantics of an array of hashes of hashes. Apart from the data in the CSV file being the same, how else is it similar to this question? Do excuse my ignorance.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: I wouldn't outright deny that. You're probably right. I have possibly fallen into that trap - I'll try to find a way out of it and make relevant edits when I can. Until then, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, in Excel I'd be looking at adding a column and just doing a `IF(B3="Y", B2, "")` type logic. But it seems odd to be duplicating the data like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#read the header row
chomp( my ( $sn, $label, @customers ) = split( /,/, <DATA> ) );
#double the 'customers' column headings (one is suffixed "_label")
print join( ",", $sn, $label, map { $_ . "_label", $_ } @customers ), "\n";

#iterate data
while (<DATA>) {
   #strip trailing linefeed
   chomp;
   #extract fields with split - note breaks if you've quoted commas inline. 
   my ( $sn, $label, @row ) = split /,/;
   print "$sn,$label,";
   #iterate Y/N values, and either prints "Y" + label, or anything else + blank. 
   foreach my $value (@row) {
      print join( ",", $value eq "Y" ? $label : "", $value ),",";
   }
   print "\n";
}


__DATA__
S.No,Label,Customer1,Customer2,Customer3
1,label1,Y,N,Y
2,label2,N,Y,N
```

Assumes you don't have any fruity special characters (e.g. commas) in the fields, because it'll break if you do, and you might want to consider `Text::CSV` instead.

Comment: LOL @ *fruity*! List assignment is good. `split /,/` is better than `split ","`

Comment: Your solution doesn't produce the *expected output*. Did I miss something?

Comment: Trailing comma. Have opted to leave empty fields completely empty rather than blank strings, because I'm pretty sure Excel doesn't care.

Comment: Wha's the difference between the two modes of `split`?

Comment: There are no *two modes*. It's just that the first parameters is compiled as a regex pattern, and using slashes for delimiters best self-documents that. Imagine `split '.', $string` which produces an empty list unless there are newlines in `$string`

Comment: Technically, there are two "modes" with the special case of `split ' ', $foo`, which is different than `split / /, $foo`. What Borodin said applies to every other case, though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Indeed. I cringe whenever I see `split /\s+/, $string` as is almost always meant to be `split ' ', $string`, which is identical to `$string =~ /\S+/g`

Comment: Thank you. There are indeed no fruity characters, so this works fine! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Borodin: Thank you for the information about the two "modes" (okay, not - two ways anyway) of `split`. That was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It is always much better to post some usable test data than write a *something like this* question

However, it looks like your data has no quoted fields or escaped characters, so it looks like you can just use `split` and `join` to process the CSV data

Here's a sample Perl program that fulfils your requirement. The example output uses your data as it is. Each line of data has to be processed backwards so that the insertions don't affect the indices of elements that are yet to be processed

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;

    for ( my $i = $#fields; $i > 1; --$i ) {

        my $newval = 
            $. == 1               ? $fields[$i] :
            lc $fields[$i] eq 'y' ? $fields[1] :
            '';

        splice @fields, $i, 0, $newval;
    }

    say join ',', @fields;
}

__DATA__
S.No,Label,Customer1,Customer2,Customer3...
1,label1,Y,N,Y
2,label2,N,Y,N
```

### output

```
S.No,Label,Customer1,Customer1,Customer2,Customer2,Customer3...,Customer3...
1,label1,label1,Y,,N,label1,Y
2,label2,,N,label2,Y,,N
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!